# Show for all positive integers l : $0 = \sum_{k=0}^ {3l-1} (-3)^{k} { 6l \choose 2k+1}$

Tags: binomial-theorem

Show for all positive integers l :

$$0 = \sum_{k=0}^ {3l-1} (-3)^{k}  { 6l \choose 2k+1}$$

My teacher said that I should note "suitable Power of $
{\sqrt 3} + i$ " and use the binomial theorem to proof this.

Comment: Welcome to math.se. Please read "How to ask a good question" https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question for information about the kinds of posts we look for. Posts that merely have a problem, with no motivation, source, or context, are discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Expand $(\sqrt3+i)^{6l}$ using the binomial theorem. (Where $6l$ is suggested by the top of that binomial coefficient in the problem statement.)
Also, what is the value of $(\sqrt3+i)^{6}$? (Use the polar representation of $\sqrt3+i$.) And don't forget that two complex numbers are equal if and only if their real and imaginary parts both match.

Comment: Good hint but im still struggling with a structured proof.

Answer (score 1):

> We obtain for integral $l>0$:
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{3l-1}\binom{6l}{2k+1}(-3)^k}
> &=\frac{1}{i\sqrt{3}}\sum_{k=0}^{3l-1}\binom{6l}{2k+1}\left(i\sqrt{3}\right)^{2k+1}\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{i\sqrt{3}}\sum_{k=0}^{6l}\binom{6l}{k}\left(i\sqrt{3}\right)^{k}\cdot\frac{1-(-1)^k}{2}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2i\sqrt{3}}\left[\left(1+i\sqrt{3}\right)^{6l}-\left(1-i\sqrt{3}\right)^{6l}\right]\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2i\sqrt{3}}\left[(-8)^{2l}-(-8)^{2l}\right]\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=0}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we change the exponent of the term $(-3)^k$ from $k$ to $2k+1$ in order to adapt it with $\binom{6l}{\color{blue}{2k+1}}$.
- In (2) we add the even terms to the sum and multiply them with $0$ by $\frac{1-(-1)^k}{2}$ when $k$ is even. This way we prepare the sum for the binomial theorem in the next step. Note the upper limit is set to $6l$.
- In (3) we split the sum and apply the  *[binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)*.
- In (4) we observe that $(1\pm i\sqrt{3})^3=-8$.

Comment: Just checking .. is there a typo on line two?

Comment: Maple says $(1\pm\sqrt{3})^3 = -8.$

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Many thanks for this hint. Corrected.

Comment: On line two you activate the even/odd filter but you did not adjust the chooser.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Thanks again. Typo corrected.

Comment: I upvoted the corrected version. The question has now been closed.